# How do I invoke type-ahead tags on mobile site?

Tags: support, tags, mobile-web

I've often typed a question, and started typing a tag. The type-ahead feature gives me interesting options to choose from.

Q: What does the mobile site expect here (on iOS device) to select tag?

I always seem to have to go through about six seconds of different touch operations before it "takes".